# A bound that follows from submodularity

Tags: co.combinatorics, optimization, pr.probability, submodularity

I am studying **Lemma 1** of this paper: [The Adaptive Complexity of Maximizing a Submodular Function](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3188745.3188752). The proof appears on page 11.

I got stuck on this inequality:

[image]

where $f$ is a monotone submodular set function, $S$ and $S^{-1}$ are two sets, $R$ is a random subset of $S$ (sampled from a uniform distribution over subsets of size $k$, where $k$ is some given value.), and $f_{R \setminus \{a\}}(a)$ is the marginal gain by adding an element $a$ to the set $R \setminus \{a\}$.

In particular, how does the second inequality follows from the submodularity of $f$?

Comment: Okay, submodularity is equivalent to a larger marginal gain if we add $a$ to a superset than the marginal gain to its subset. I can see an intuition that if we assume $a \in R$, then $R\setminus \{a\}$ is a smaller set. Whereas if $a \not\in R$, then $R \setminus \{a\} = R$ which is a large, so $a$ gives a larger marginal gain in the first place. But I don't immediately see that as compatible with conditional probability. It seems to rely on something you haven't told us about $R$, like each element is included with equal independent probability.

Comment: @usul $R$ is a random subset of $S$, sampled from a uniform distribution over subsets of size $k$, where $k$ is some given value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lemma implies the inequality in question.

**Lemma 1.** $E[f_{R\setminus \{a\}}(a)] \le E[f_{R\setminus\{a\}}(a) \,|\, a \in R]$

*Proof.* Consider the following experiment:

1. Let $R$ be distributed as in the question (uniformly at random from the size-$k$ subsets).
2. Obtain r.v.'s $R_1$ and $R_2$ from $R$ as follows: if $a\in R$, let $R_1=R_2=R$. Otherwise let $R_1 = R \cup\{a\}$ and let $R_2 = (R \setminus \{x\})\cup\{a\}$ where $x$ is a random element from $R$.

Note the following:

3. In any outcome
   $f_{R_1\setminus \{a\}}(a) \le f_{R_2\setminus\{a\}}(a),$
   because $f$ is submodular and $R_2 \subseteq R_1$.
4. $R_2$ is distributed uniformly at random from the size-$k$ sets containing $a$.  That is, the distribution of $R_2$ is the distribution of $R$ conditioned on $a\in R$.

Now we have

$\begin{align*}
E[f_{R\setminus\{a\}}(a)]
& = E[f_{R_1\setminus\{a\}}(a)]
&& (\text{because } R\setminus\{a\} = R_1\setminus\{a\})
\\
& \le E[f_{R_2\setminus\{a\}}(a)]
&& (\text{by item 3 above})
\\
& = E[f_{R\setminus\{a\}}(a)\,|\, a\in R]
&& (\text{by item 4 above})~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Box
\end{align*}$

---